# Is there a way to tell NLTK that a certain word isn't a proper noun but a noun?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm doing some NLP where I'm finding out when patients were diagnosed with multiple sclerosis.

I'd like to use nltk to tell me that the noun of a sentence was multiple sclerosis. Problem is, doctors frequently refer to multiple sclerosis as MS which nltk picks up as a proper noun.

For example, this sentence, "His MS was diagnosed in 1999." Is tagged as: `[('His', 'PRP$'), ('MS', 'NNP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('diagnosed', 'VBN'), ('in', 'IN'), ('1999', 'CD'), ('.', '.')]`

MS should be a noun here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Named entity recognition is a difficult problem. Try [this](http://textminingonline.com/how-to-use-stanford-named-entity-recognizer-ner-in-python-nltk-and-other-programming-languages).

Comment: Your using default POS Taggers currently.  So in that case you need to train your own corpus with including the correct POS tagged values. If not as a fall back mechanism you should have another error correction layer after using default corpus POS Tagger model.

Comment: What is the source of the data? Is it possible to share? Is there a list of words/phrases/abbreviations that you want them to always be nouns? Do you have tagged data? What is the domain of the data? What is ultimate purpose of the POS tagging? Answering those questions would narrow down the solutions to your questions.

Comment: In your particular example, you can just post-process the tagged data and change `('MS', 'NNP')` to `('MS', 'NN')`. But I'm guessing you don't want that, you want a perfect tagger. Have you thought about how you're going to determine which words to override?

Comment: If 'MS' isn't your only instance and you want to do this large scale, I would probably look into Word sense disambiguation and use a medical dictionary as a basis for the most likely meaning of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Summing it up, you have the following options:

1. Correcting the tag in the post-processing - a bit ugly but quick and easy.
2. Employ an external *Name Entity Recognizer* (Stanford NER as @Bob Dylan has thoughtfully suggested) - this one is more involved, particularly because Stanford NER is in java and is not particularly fast.
3. Retrain a POS Tagger on domain-specific data (do you have a large enough annotated dataset to use it for that?)
4. Use *WSD* (Word Sense Disambiguation) approach - for a start you need to have a good domain dictionary to use.